# Magento 2.1 re-indexing issue

Tags: php, magento, reindex

I am using Magento 2.1

I have an issue that after i re-index products get hidden. I do have a work around but this is not good. Let me explain how I reproduce error then what i do to fix.

1. Upload via emagic 7000 products
2. I notice as the products are been loaded that the front end is looking good
3. After upload products automatically indexed (or i run index command)
4. Products are hidden from front end
   ( i.e
     1 page should have 1,500 products but now only shows 500
      another page should have 6,000 products but now only shows 500
      and a page showing all records with 7,500 now only shows 500)

I can fix this by doing the following
1. run this sql query to disable all products
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int SET value =0 WHERE attribute_id =94

2. run re-index command
   php bin/magento indexer:reindex
3. run sql query to enable all products
   UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int SET value =1 WHERE attribute_id =94
4. run re-index command
   php bin/magento indexer:reindex
5. run this command (twice)
   php bin/magento cron:run
   php bin/magento cron:run

then all products display again. but if i run re-index again I have to repeat steps i to 5 to get working again which is not very good.

I also notice that the below 2 commands cause the issue, all other index commands run seperatly cause no problems
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_category_product
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_category

How can I fix this permanently? any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue after completely clearing all products (truncating MYSQL) I did the following two steps

1. Followed the details in the below link to truncate all tables that to delete all data ready for re-import. Obviously get a back up of your data to re-import first
2. Checked mysql and truncated all tables in mysql beginning with 'catalog_' EXCEPT catalog_product_link_type

3.logeed in as ssh and ran the following commands
cd public_html
php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex

## Delete the static view files directory and compile directory

rm -rf var/di
mkdir var/di
rm -rf var/generation
mkdir var/generation
cd pub/static
rm -rf _cache
rm -rf deployed_version.txt
rm -rf frontend
rm -rf _requirejs
rm -rf adminhtml
cd ..
cd ..
php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php -f bin/magento cache:clean
php -f bin/magento cache:flush
php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex

4. Then I removed all product related images (again back up for re-import)
   rm -rf /pub/media/catalog/product
   mkdir /pub/media/catalog/product

That worked for me, just started cleared the database and all files ready for re-import